# Cannot decrypt the password in application.yml properly if war file in the tomcat/webapps

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

Spring boot version:3.2.3

Tomcat version:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.19"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.19"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.19\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21.0.2"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.19\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Users\zhibo\Desktop\Apache\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.
```

Jasypt version:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is the issue, in IDEA I can encrypt/decrpyt the database password properly which in the `application.yml` file. However when I generate the war file and put it in tomcat and try to start up the program I got following exception:

```
Reason: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES  SecretKeyFactory not available
```

And I setup the values in the `catalina.properties` file with following properties:

```
jasypt.encryptor.password=password 
jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES 
jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname=org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
```

What should I do to fix this ?

Comment: Sounds like a difference in the runtime environment. Which java versions do you use in IDEA and which version to run your tomcat?

Comment: @f1sh also Java 21.0.2.. and Apache Tomcat/10.1.19

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue... The way I encryprt my password was using `StandardPBEStringEncryptor`, and that is why I cannot choose the proper algorithm for that. Once I choose the `PooledPBEStringEncryptor` and following the example on the github to do the config, encrypt works. And I put all the jasypt config except password part into `application.yml` and the `jasypt.encryptor.password` was set in the catalina.properties` for the tomcat, everything solved now